# Fuzzy String Searching with Whoosh in Python

Tags: python, information-retrieval, fuzzy-search, whoosh

I've built up a large database of banks in MongoDB. I can easily take this information and create indexes with it in whoosh.  For example I'd like to be able to match the bank names 'Eagle Bank & Trust Co of Missouri' and 'Eagle Bank and Trust Company of Missouri'. The following code works with simple fuzzy such, but cannot achieve a match on the above:

```
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *

schema = Schema(name=TEXT(stored=True))
ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
writer = ix.writer()

test_items = [u"Eagle Bank and Trust Company of Missouri"]

writer.add_document(name=item)
writer.commit()

from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
from whoosh.query import FuzzyTerm

with ix.searcher() as s:
    qp = QueryParser("name", schema=ix.schema, termclass=FuzzyTerm)
    q = qp.parse(u"Eagle Bank & Trust Co of Missouri")
    results = s.search(q)
    print results
```

gives me:

```
<Top 0 Results for And([FuzzyTerm('name', u'eagle', boost=1.000000, minsimilarity=0.500000, prefixlength=1), FuzzyTerm('name', u'bank', boost=1.000000, minsimilarity=0.500000, prefixlength=1), FuzzyTerm('name', u'trust', boost=1.000000, minsimilarity=0.500000, prefixlength=1), FuzzyTerm('name', u'co', boost=1.000000, minsimilarity=0.500000, prefixlength=1), FuzzyTerm('name', u'missouri', boost=1.000000, minsimilarity=0.500000, prefixlength=1)]) runtime=0.00166392326355>
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want with Whoosh? If not what other python based solutions do I have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You could** match `Co` with `Company` using Fuzzy Search in Whoosh but **You shouldn't** do  because the difference between `Co` and `Company` is large. `Co` is similar to `Company` as `Be` is similar to `Beast` and `ny` to `Company`, You can imagine how bad and how large will be the search results.

However, if you want to match `Compan` or `compani` or `Companee` to `Company` you could do it by using a Personalized Class of `FuzzyTerm` with default `maxdist` equal to 2 or more :

> **maxdist** – The maximum edit distance from the given text.

```
class MyFuzzyTerm(FuzzyTerm):
     def __init__(self, fieldname, text, boost=1.0, maxdist=2, prefixlength=1, constantscore=True):
         super(MyFuzzyTerm, self).__init__(fieldname, text, boost, maxdist, prefixlength, constantscore)
```

Then:

```
 qp = QueryParser("name", schema=ix.schema, termclass=MyFuzzyTerm)
```

You could match `Co` with `Company` by setting `maxdist` to `5` but this as I said give bad search results. I suggest to keep `maxdist` from `1` to `3`.

If you are looking for matching a word linguistic variations, you better use [`whoosh.query.Variations`](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/query.html#whoosh.query.Variations).

**Note:** older Whoosh versions has `minsimilarity` instead of `maxdist`.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, and there must be a better way to do this somehow, but here's my shot.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import whoosh
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *
from whoosh.query import *
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser

schema = Schema(name=TEXT(stored=True))
idx = create_in("C:\\idx_name\\", schema, "idx_name")

writer = idx.writer()

writer.add_document(name=u"This is craaazy shit")
writer.add_document(name=u"This is craaazy beer")
writer.add_document(name=u"Raphaël rocks")
writer.add_document(name=u"Rockies are mountains")

writer.commit()

s = idx.searcher()
print "Fields: ", list(s.lexicon("name"))
qp = QueryParser("name", schema=schema, termclass=FuzzyTerm)

for i in range(1,40):
    res = s.search(FuzzyTerm("name", "just rocks", maxdist=i, prefixlength=0))
    if len(res) > 0:
        for r in res:
            print "Potential match ( %s ): [  %s  ]" % ( i, r["name"] )
        break
    else:
        print "Pass: %s" % i

s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some of this stuff might help (string matching open sourced by the seatgeek guys):

https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this question more recently, it looks like they've added fuzzy support natively, though it'd take a bit of work to satisfy the particular use case outlined here: https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parsing.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32073661)

Answer (score -3):

You could use this function below to fuzz search a set of words against a phrase:

```
def FuzzySearch(text, phrase):
    """Check if word in phrase is contained in text"""
    phrases = phrase.split(" ")

    for x in range(len(phrases)):
        if phrases[x] in text:
            print("Match! Found " + phrases[x] + " in text")
        else:
            continue
```